# RxJs. Combining latest and once

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a UI like this:

[image]

Where I can

- Enter something in search box
- Drag users from table to chart

The logic required is:

- Initially chart shows some subset of all users (e.g., first 10)
- When users are dragged on chart they are added to the users that already there
- When filter is applied all users are removed from chart and then it is repopulated with some subset of matching users

I am trying to implement such logic with RxJs.
I have `filteredUsers$` and `addedUsers$` stream that produce users matching filter and dragged users correspondingly.

I need to combine them in such way:

```
        Observable
            .<OPERATOR>(filteredUsers$, addedUsers$)
            .subscribe(([filteredUsers, addedUsers]) => {
                // When filteredUsers$ fires:
                //   filteredUsers is value from stream
                //   addedUsers == null

                // When addedUsers$ fires:
                //   filteredUsers is latest available value
                //   addedUsers is value from stream

                redrawChart(/* combining users */)
            });
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Time sequence:

```
Filtered: -  a  -  -  -  -  a  -  ->
Added   : -  -  b  -  b  -  -  -  ->
Result  : -  a  ab -  ab -  a  -  ->
```

Comment: Probably, you're looking for the 'zip' operator.

Comment: @Zozo, look at the time sequence. Zip will result in two 'ab' events. But I need different output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the final stream to be populated only when addUsers$ fires with latest from could be a solution:

[image]

So, in your case addUsers$ could be the first stream. 
You can try out the following code:

```
 let firstObservable$ = Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4])
    .zip(Observable.interval(50), (a, b) => {
      return a;
    });

  let secondObservable$ = Observable.from([5, 6])
    .zip(
      Observable.interval(70), (a, b) => {
        return a;
      });

  firstObservable$
    .withLatestFrom(secondObservable$, (f, s) => ({ a: f, b: s }))
    .subscribe(x => {
      console.log('result: ', x);
    });
```

The first observable emits every 50 ms a value from the array.
The second observable every 75 ms.

The values printed are {a: 2, b: 5} {a: 3, b: 6} {a: 4, b: 6}

*Because 1 was emitted before 5 we lose the pair (1,5)!*

I am not clear but missing a pair from addUsers$ if the other stream has not emitted may be non-desired behavior for you.
You could overcome that if you start the second stream with an initial value and then filter out any results you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

You have the combineLatest operator which basically does what you are describing. It combines two observables and gives you the latest value of both streams.

So:

--a--b-----c---
-x-----d-----p-
-combineLatest-
--a--b-b---c-c
  x  x d   d p

This should allow you to do what you want if I understand correctly.

Here's the official doc link:
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md

Comment: Combine latest will result in both `filteredUsers` and `addedUsers` are being populated in subscribe. But I want them to be both populated only when `addedUsers$` fires.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I have done it by adding additional subject:

```
var filteredUsers$ = ... // users from filter
var addedUsers$ = ... // users dragged on chart
var usersToDraw$ = new Subject();
```

subscriptions:

```
usersToDraw$
    .subscribe(usersToDraw => {
        redrawChart(usersToDraw);
    });

filteredUsers$
    .subscribe(filteredUsers => {
        usersToDraw$.next(filteredUsers);
    });

Observable
    .combineLatest(filteredUsers$, addedUsers$)
    .filter(([filteredUsers, addedUsers]) => addedUsers != null)
    .subscribe(([filteredUsers, addedUsers]) => {
        // we 'clear' stream so the same users won't be added twice 
        addedUsers$.next(null);

        usersToDraw$.next(/* combining users */);
    });
```

**UPDATE**

The solution can be improved with `withLatestFrom` (thanks @nova)

```
usersToDraw$
    .subscribe(usersToDraw => {
        redrawChart(usersToDraw);
    });

filteredUsers$
    .subscribe(filteredUsers => {
        usersToDraw$.next(filteredUsers);
    });

addedUsers$
    .withLatestFrom(filteredUsers$)
    .subscribe(([addedUsers, filteredUsers]) => {
        usersToDraw$.next(/* combining users */);
    });
```